# Spring security redirects https pages to login

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security

I have an application secured with spring security.

To tell the story on short:

Many requests to unsecured resources (like images or other assets) were done on https (some of the requests from another applications). Spring security was setup like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="http" />
```

(other paths being secured specifically).

This was causing a problem, performing a redirect (302 response) to the same resource url but with http.
The applications were asking that resource would brake down of this. The result was to embed on an https page unprotected resources (coming from http).

I thought that a solution was to put requires-channel="any" having in mind that this won't perform the redirect.

The issue now is that any request to https makes a redirect to the login page from spring security and it seems I cannot find any setup in the config file to do that and neither any info in the docs.

Can somebody help me with some ideas?

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:anonymous username="anonymous" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />

        <!-- session stealing is prevented by using secure GUID cookie -->
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

        <!-- SSL / AUTHENTICATED pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/my-account*" access="ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP" requires-channel="https" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/my-account/**" access="ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP" requires-channel="https" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" /> <!-- Everything else should be insecure -->

        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
                authentication-success-handler-ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler"  />

<security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />

        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.http.port')}"
                https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.ssl.port')}" />
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
            <!--security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('proxy.http.port')}"
                https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('proxy.ssl.port')}" /-->
        </security:port-mappings>

        <security:request-cache ref="httpSessionRequestCache" />

</security:http>
```

Comment: Can you please post your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Rob, I've put the config below in an answer(too long for a response).
I've skipped some other mappings because of confidentiality (are lines like <security:intercept-url pattern="/register" requires-channel="https" />)